# $a^2-2b^2=-73696$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, natural-numbers

How to find all pairs $(a,b)$ of natural numbers that satisfy
$a^2-2b^2=-73696$ and $\gcd(a,b)=4$

The only thing I was able to do is to change the equation to

$a_1^2-2b_1^2=-4606$ with $\gcd(a_1,b_1)=1$
This gives that $2|a_1$ so the equation becomes $2a_2^2-b_1^2=-2303$ ,$2a_2=a_1$

I can't find useful bound or factorization to complete
, Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Notice $b_1$ must be odd

Comment: So that nobody tries wasting time proving that there exist no pairs, note that there do exist solutions.  The list begins $(56,196),~(152,220),~(248,260),~(296,284),~(424,356),\dots$

Comment: there are infinitely many solutions

Comment: @willJagy can we prove that it has infinitely many solutions??

Comment: As an aside, using a terribly inefficient brute force that I threw together in a few seconds and let it run for several minutes, the largest with $a<3000000$ it found was $(267224,188956)$

Comment: I realize now that I had not checked the condition that $\gcd(a,b)=4$, so some on my list such as $(56,196)$ are invalid as they only checked if $a^2-2b^2=-73696$, but we do have $\gcd(152,220)=\gcd(248,260)=\gcd(296,284)=4$ and very likely several others on the list, including the large one I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: @JMoravitz is there a general solution for this question?

Comment: Cf. [generalized Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Generalized_Pell's_equation)

Answer (score 1):

Use the famous identity

$\begin{array}\\
(u^2-nv^2)(x^2-ny^2)
&=u^2x^2-nu^2y^2-nv^2x^2+n^2v^2y^2\\
&=u^2x^2+n^2v^2y^2-n(u^2y^2+v^2x^2)\\
&=u^2x^2+2nu^2v^2x^2y^2+n^2v^2y^2-n(u^2y^2+2u^2v^2x^2y^2+v^2x^2)\\
&=(ux+nvy)^2-n(uy+vx)^2\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if there is a solution to
$x^2-ny^2=1$,
then,
if $u^2-nv^2=d$,
there are an infinite number of solutions to
$u_m^2-nv_m^2=d$
starting with
$u_1=u, v_1=v$
and
$u_{m+1}=u_mx+nv_my,
v_{m+1}=u_my+v_mx
$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem lives naturally in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt2]$ with norm $N(x+y\sqrt2)=x^2-2y^2$ and [Brahmagupta's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity) is very useful; it says that the norm is multiplicative.

Write $a^2-2b^2=-73696 =  2^4 \cdot 7^2 \cdot (-2) \cdot 47$.

If
$x_1^2-2y_1^2=-2$,
$x_2^2-2y_2^2=47$,
then we can get
$x_3^2-2y_3^2=(-2) \cdot 47$
using [Brahmagupta's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity).
Finally we get $a=2^2\cdot 7 \cdot x_4$ and $b=2^2\cdot 7 \cdot y_4$.

Carrying out this plan, we start with $(x_1,y_1)=(0,1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(7,1)$, found by inspection. Then $(x_3,y_3)=(2,7)$ and $(a,b)=(56,196)$.

You get infinitely many solutions of $a^2-2b^2=-73696$ by using [Brahmagupta's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity) with even powers of $1+\sqrt2$, that is, powers of $3+2\sqrt2$.

Since $\gcd(56,196)=4$, this continues to hold because $(x+y\sqrt2)(3+2\sqrt2)$ can be expressed as
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}
$$
and the matrix has determinant $1$.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many solutions and they come with a  linear  degree two recursion. I was finding $x^2 - 2 y^2 = 2303$

The first observation is a generator for the (oriented) automorphism group of the quadratic form
$$  x^2 - 2 y^2 = (3x+4y)^2 - 2(2x+3y)^2  $$
As your target $2303$  is composite we need six families of solutions  as
$$  x_{n+6}  = 3x_n + 4 y_n $$
$$  y_{n+6}  = 2x_n + 3 y_n $$

These have parallel recurrences
$$x_{n+12} = 6 x_{n+6}  - x_n $$
$$y_{n+12} = 6 y_{n+6}  - y_n $$

I think I will include the inequality part, this is how the business gets proved. The solutions that my program, below, calls "seeds" are those $x,y >0 $   such that either $3x-4y \leq 0$   or  $-2x+3y \leq 0.$  The $3x-4y$ condition causes no restrictions, but the second, $y \leq \frac{2x}{3},$  gives firm upper bounds on both $x,y.$  Finding where the line intersects the hyperbola, we learn $x < \sqrt {20727} \approx  143.9687,$   with the $y$ bound two thirds of that. And there are exactly six such fundamental solutions.
[image]

let me type in the lists

as the $x$ begin
$$  49, 55, 65, 71, 89, 119, 175, 241, 319, 361, 479, 665, 1001, 1391 $$

while the $y$ begin

$$7,  19,  31,  37,  53,  77,  119,  167,  223,  253,  
337,  469,  707,  983,  1307,  1481,  1969,  2737,  4123,  5731,$$

let me throw in the pairs list   which has the line numbers I am calling $n$

```
 w^2 - 2 v^2 = 2303 =  7^2 47

Tue 27 Feb 2024 10:07:10 AM PST

1. x:  49 =  7^2      y: 7 =  7  SEED   KEEP +- 
2. x:  55 =  5 11      y: 19 =  19  SEED   KEEP +- 
3. x:  65 =  5 13      y: 31 =  31  SEED   KEEP +- 
4. x:  71 =  71      y: 37 =  37  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  65 ,  -31
5. x:  89 =  89      y: 53 =  53  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  55 ,  -19
6. x:  119 =  7 17      y: 77 =  7 11  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  49 ,  -7
7. x:  175 =  5^2 7      y: 119 =  7 17
8. x:  241 =  241      y: 167 =  167
9. x:  319 =  11 29      y: 223 =  223
10. x:  361 =  19^2      y: 253 =  11 23
11. x:  479 =  479      y: 337 =  337
12. x:  665 =  5 7 19      y: 469 =  7 67
13. x:  1001 =  7 11 13      y: 707 =  7 101
14. x:  1391 =  13 107      y: 983 =  983
15. x:  1849 =  43^2      y: 1307 =  1307
16. x:  2095 =  5 419      y: 1481 =  1481
17. x:  2785 =  5 557      y: 1969 =  11 179
18. x:  3871 =  7^2 79      y: 2737 =  7 17 23
19. x:  5831 =  7^3 17      y: 4123 =  7 19 31
20. x:  8105 =  5 1621      y: 5731 =  11 521
21. x:  10775 =  5^2 431      y: 7619 =  19 401
22. x:  12209 =  29 421      y: 8633 =  89 97
23. x:  16231 =  16231      y: 11477 =  23 499
24. x:  22561 =  7 11 293      y: 15953 =  7 43 53
25. x:  33985 =  5 7 971      y: 24031 =  7 3433
```

Comment: How did you find that recursive relations ?

Comment: @Mostafadd  it is the Cayley Hamilton theorem for the "automorphism"  matrix associated with this way to get new solutions from old:  $$  x^2 - 2 y^2 = (3x+4y)^2 - 2(2x+3y)^2  $$

Comment: As I understand what you wrote , it's enough to find only one pair of natural numbers that satisfy the condition, then we can find infinitely many solutions using this expression, Am I right ?

Comment: @Mostafadd  if you just want to show there are infinitely many, yes. I found all the solutions, and that splits into six families  for this particular problem

Comment: thanks,last question: why 6 ,why we write $x_{n+6}$ not anything else like $x_{n+4}$ or something?

Comment: Pair number $1,$ is $(49,7).$  Under the rule $  x^2 - 2 y^2 = (3x+4y)^2 - 2(2x+3y)^2  $  the new pair is $(175,119)$  which is pair number $7.$  Apply the rule again to get $(1001, 707)$ which is pair 13

Comment: Why $(175,119$ is the pair number 7 ?

Comment: @Mostafadd   these are the line numbers in the section of computer output at the bottom of my answer.